# What do you call it when everything satisfies one condition or the other?

Tags: phrase-requests

When something can be A or B but not both, A and B are **mutually exclusive**. As sets, A and B would be disjoint.

When everything must be A or B—that is, a thing may be A or B or both, but not neither—*what are A and B called*? A and B need not be mutually exclusive, but not-A and not-B definitely are.

Here are some examples.

> Somebody took cookies from the cookie jar! It could have been Sally or Timmy, but let's not forget that they might be in cahoots; it being Sally or Timmy is **[as described above]**, after all.
>
> If you want to get technical, heads and tails results on a coin are not **[as described above]**, because you missed the very tiny chance that the coin lands on its side.
>
> Clearly, a signed graph cannot at once have a blocknode and two disjoint odd circuits—the two conditions are mutually exclusive. Ideally, they are also **[as described above]**, but as we will show, this is not the case.

To be clear, I'm not looking for mathematical terminology, but something a fluent English speaker could recognize.

Comment: They are ***the only two options*** - maybe *binary options* (although this has a different meaning in the stock market.)

Comment: Note though, that I could perform my 5th backup on the 90th day.

Comment: @Jim I feel *option* carries the connotation that you must chose one, and further that you could abstain from choosing altogether. I am seeking to describe the opposite: you can have one or the other or both, but not neither.

Comment: The truth table for this function is 0 1 1 0, that is ≠ aka *not equal*. So maybe you could call the choice a *trade-off* or call the options *opposites*. Not perfect yet, but reducing this to its essentials (≠) seems to lead in promising directions.

Comment: @DanBron Incorrect, I am looking for logical OR.

Comment: @algorithmshark No, you're not. Logical OR is true if p is true or q is true or *both are true*. What you want is logical XOR, aka ≠ (since you're looking for a non-technical word understood by everyday people, it will probably be more fruitful to pursue "not equal" and its synonyms rather than "exclusive or").

Comment: @DanBron I am well aware. Please read the question. "--that is, a thing may be A or B or both, but not neither--"

Comment: @algorithmshark I misunderstood you - the example made me think it wasn't possible for 90 days and 5 backups to have occurred, because logically one is going to happen first.

Comment: @DanBron Yeah, that example's been problematic. I've tried to come up with slightly better ones, see edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would label A and B as "**mutually/collectively/jointly exhaustive events**". It's a standard math jargon if you go and read about a concept called Venn Diagram. Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: This is [exactly what I was looking for](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collectively_exhaustive_events).

Answer (score 1):

This gets sticky, but I suppose you're talking about inclusivity. In your first example, either *inclusive* or, more commonly, *all-inclusive*, works:

> The money-back policy on the backup software is valid for up to 90 days or 5 backups. The two conditions are all-inclusive.

For your second example, just *inclusive* seems to fit the case (you tell me--I'm not familiar with the discourse domain):

> Clearly, a signed graph cannot at once have a blocknode and two disjoint odd circuits—the two conditions are mutually exclusive. Ideally, they are also inclusive, but as we will show, this is not the case.

Comment: While the definition of inclusive seems to cover the case, I haven't ever seen or heard it used like this. If nothing better comes up, this may have to do.

Answer (score 0):

**And/or** is quite common, ordinary speech included. You could tell someone on the phone: "The money-back policy on the backup software is valid for up to 90 days *and or* 5 backups." A fluent English speaker would have no problem with it.

Comment: "Clearly, ... the two conditions are mutually exclusive. Ideally, they are also *and/or*, but as we will show, this is not the case." This doesn't parse quite right. I'm looking for a phrase that would fit both examples naturally.